# Extract number from address with regex

Tags: php, regex, street-address

I need to extract number from french addresses.

Here is my regex:

```
\d+( |\d+|bte|-|boite|[\w] {1}|([a-z] ){1}){0,2}
```

Example on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/ZP8DSV/1
It's partialy working but not for all the lines.

I need to extract the number + extra info.

If I take this list, it should give me this (for each line):

```
|---------------------------------------|--------------|
|              Original                 |     Result   |
|---------------------------------------|--------------|
| rue hovémont 3                        | 3            |
| rue hovémont 3-5                      | 3-5          |
| rue hovémont 3 5                      | 3 5          |
| Rue hovémont 35                       | 35           |
| Rue hovémont 46 A                     | 46 A         |
| Rue hovémont 46 A1                    | 46 A1        |
| 46 A1 Rue hovémont                    | 46 A1        |
| 46 A Rue hovémont                     | 46 A         |
| Rue du pont de pierre, 1              | 1            |
| Chaussée d alseg 416 c                | 416 c        |
| Chaussée d alseg, 416 c               | 416 c        |
| Chaussée d alseg 416c                 | 416c         |
| Chaussée d alseg, 416c                | 416c         |
| 416 c Chaussée d alseg                | 416 c        |
| 416 c, Chaussée d alseg               | 416 c        |
| 416c Chaussée d alseg                 | 416c         |
| 416c, Chaussée d alseg                | 416c         |
| Square de la demi-lune 7 boite 5      | 7 boite 5    |
| 7 boite 5 Square de la demi-lune      | 7 boite 5    |
| Rue aux laines 150/58                 | 150/58       |
| Rue de la forêt, 95                   | 95           |
| Chaussée d'anvers 294                 | 294          |
| Avenue jean sébastien bach, 24 bte 32 | 24 bte 32    |
| 10 bte 1 rue des volontaires          | 10 bte 1     |
| Rue du 5ème Tïme 5 bte 2              | 5 bte 2      |
| Rue du 5eme Tïme 5 bte 2              | 5 bte 2      |
| Rue du 5 eme Tïme 5 bte 2             | 5 bte 2      |
| Rue du 5 ème Tïme 5 bte 2             | 5 bte 2      |
| Rue du 1 er Tïme 5 bte 2              | 5 bte 2      |
| 20a Test Strasse                      | 20a          |
|---------------------------------------|--------------|
```

Can you help me on this case ? :)

Comment: You right. It is 46 A1. Thank you.

Comment: If this is the whole list, it's doable. If you want to extract the number for random given adresses, it's impossible to get them all right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a working regex to capture your text starting with a digit either at start or at the end:

```sh
^\d\w*(?:\h+(?>boite|bte|\pL\d?|\d)\b)*|\h\K\d+\pL?(?:[-/]\d+|\h+(?:boite|bte|\pL\d?|\d+)\b)*$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/acOd3q/1)

For PHP use following:

```sh
$re = '~^\d\w*(?:\h+(?>boite|bte|\pL\d?|\d)\b)*|\h\K\d+\pL?(?:[-/]\d+|\h+(?:boite|bte|\pL\d?|\d+)\b)*$~miu'
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\d\w*`: Match a word starting with a digit
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?>boite|bte|\pL\d?|\d)`: Match `boite` or `bte` or a single digit or a letter optionally followed by a digit
  - `\b`: Word boundary
- `)*`: End non-capture group. Match 0 or more of this group.
- `|`: OR
- `\h`: Match a whitespace
- `\K`: reset the match
- `\d+\pL?`: Match 1+ digit followed by an optional letter
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?:[-/]\d+|\h+(?:boite|bte|\pL\d?|\d+)\b)*`: Match remaining parts
- `$`: End

Comment: Fantastic! I don't have this approach.
I updated my example with three more lines. How can I use your regex with spaces between spaces and "ème" or "er" ?

Comment: Great for the list OP has given. But it fails for adresses with numbers in the streetname, like _Place du 14 Juillet 16_

Comment: Examples added @anubhava :)

Comment: @anubhava You are absolutely right, you can't get every case.. But my initial tought: this is just some random example list, has just been proven right by de update OP made.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry. here is the link: https://regex101.com/r/zzZWT7/1

Comment: @anubhava Thank you! But some examples are'nt working now :(
Maybe just use a filter on "ème","eme" and "er" ?

Comment: For `Rue du 5 ème Tïme 5 bte 2` it captures `5 bte 2` as per your expected output right?

Comment: Yes but `Rue aux laines 150/58` is not working anymore

Comment: Thank you! Juste on example is not working now `rue hovémont 3-5`

Comment: Perfect! One address return a wrong result `Avenue jean sébastien bach, 24 bte 32`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help @anubhava!